# Calculating distance between an array of vertices

Tags: javascript

I am using a library which has a face with 70 vertices, Is there a quick way/ loop that I can use to calculate the distance between all the vertices and say for instance I want to insert the distance between point 32 and point 27 and insert it into a div. I am currently using this to get the coordinates of each point.

```
 var position = ctrack.getCurrentPosition();
                             edx1 = position[27][0];//Eyeposition left
                             edy1 = position[27][1];

                             edx2 = position[32][0];//Eyeposition Right
                             edy2 = position[32][1];
```

and then calculating the difference using pythagoras theorem, which seems very slow and was wondering whether there was better way?

```
var distBetweenEyes = Math.sqrt( (edx1-edx2)*(edx1-edx2) + (edy1-edy2)*(edy1-edy2) );
```

diagram of the vertices below

[image]

I am wondering if I can do this on the fly, say I have a loop which calculates the distance between all 70 points then I want to be able to store the distance between any two points quickly so I can push that information to my html.

Comment: Tip: if you're just using the distance for comparison, use a distance squared comparison, so you don't have to deal with the slow sqrt function.

Comment: Looping through the data and calculating the distances between all 70 points(that would be 70C2, or 2415, pairs) doesn't seem like a good idea, considering you will only be using a handful of them. Just make a function that takes two vertices and gives you the distance between them, and call it when you need it

Comment: Would you care to expand, I found the solution I used on SO in another question. I am a beginner at this kind of thing.

Comment: @tewathia would you give me a structure for that? As I said above, I am not a competent programmer.

Comment: @DanW See http://stackoverflow.com/a/23742224/3003352

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
function distance(i, j, data) {
    return Math.pow(data[i][0] - data[j][0], 2) + Math.pow(data[i][1] - data[j][1], 2);
}
```

(you don't need to get the square root value to do comparisons, as pointed out by Meredith)

Then get the required distance with:

```
var distBetweenEyes = distance(27, 32, position);
```

Comment: I get Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined emote.html:474
distance emote.html:474
(anonymous function)

on this line : 

return Math.pow(data[i][0] - data[j][0], 2) + Math.pow(data[i][1] - data[j][1], 2);

Comment: @DanW There's nothing wrong with the function definition, I've merely restructured your code. Could be a problem with the `position` variable, see http://jsfiddle.net/tewathia/j5Bqd/1/

Comment: I am trying to understand your JsFiddle, i and j represent the two different points correct? so 27 and 32? What is positions doing? In my post I used var position = ctrack.getCurrentPosition(); to retrieve a position by passing position[27][0] and position[27][1] which would give me the x and y of vertice 27.

For reference, this is the structure I was using before which worked but is not really efficient http://pastebin.com/wmFDtrrd

Comment: Im struggling to understand your code, implementing it just returns 45? Using my code how would I implement this for the points 27 and 32?

Comment: @DanW Yes `i` and `j` represent the two points(so 27 and 32, for the two eyes) and the `position` variable contains the information about these two points. And 45 is there just as an example(for i = 0, j = 1 and a dummy `position`). Can you show me the contents of your `position` array/object?

Comment: Within the position variable you have put 3,5 and 9,2 ? how would I put in the actual coordinates by using var position = ctrack.getCurrentPosition();

Comment: I don't know what `ctrack` is, but if the code in your question works, my function should work too

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/53980/discussion-between-dan-w-and-tewathia).

Comment: @Dan W - one thing to note (in case you hadn't already) is the distance between two points is  sqrt(( x1-x2)^2   + (y1-y2)^2 )  - what tewathia has provided lacks the outer Sqrt  (square root) so the real distance is sqrt (45) - in Javascript this is Math.sqrt(45).